# What configuration is necessary for fail2ban to be useful?

Tags: fail2ban

If I simply install fail2ban on my server with `sudo apt-get install fail2ban` without configuring anything, does this provide adequate protection?

It seems that fail2ban comes with 1-2 pages of jails set up already which seem like they'd catch everything. Is any configuration necessary, or is just installing fail2ban enough?

Comment: What services are you trying to use `fail2ban` with? It is very hard to know in advance if you don't specify them.

Comment: Currently SSH and ownCloud. I'm planning to add a mail server and possibly other web apps as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a masterclass.

Answer (score 1):

`fail2ban` is a tool. A *helpful* tool, but a tool nonetheless.

In order for it to be useful to you, you need to understand:

1. What you're trying to protect against
2. If the tool adequately mitigates these concerns

Unfortunately none of us can answer these questions for you.